# i try to open a pdf in java but it s not working

Tags: java

i m trying to open a pdf by clicking a button. the path is actually right (i could open it in my browser) but it does not work. What exactly is the problem?

here is the output:

file:/Users/miladvosoughi/Documents/Prak/schach/target/classes/mainMenu/ba.pdf

File is not exists!

```
    private void openHelpPDF() {
         
        try {
            String adr = getClass()
                    .getResource("/mainMenu/ba.pdf").toString();
            
            System.out.println(adr);
            
            File pdfFile = new File(adr);
            if (pdfFile.exists()) {

                if (Desktop.isDesktopSupported()) {
                    Desktop.getDesktop().open(pdfFile);
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Awt Desktop is not supported!");
                }

            } else {
                System.out.println("File is not exists!");
            }

     
          } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
          }
        
    }
```

Comment: The `String` argument for the `new File()` constructor expects a path, not an URI. If you want to use an URI you can use the `new File()` constructor which expect an `URI` object.

Comment: @Progman thanks for the answer. Can i convert URI to Path? and how when is possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`String adr = getClass().getResource("/mainMenu/ba.pdf").toString();` *does not* return a filename.  [The object returned from Class.getResource is a URL.](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Class.html#getResource%28java.lang.String%29)

An application resource is not a file.  You cannot safely assume it is a file, ever.

If you want to pass a resource, you must copy the resource URL to a temporary file, and open that:

```
Path pdf = Files.createTempFile(null, ".pdf");
try (InputStream source =
    getClass().getResourceAsStream("/mainMenu/ba.pdf")) {

    Files.copy(source, pdf,
        StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
}

Desktop.getDesktop().open(pdf.toFile());
```